# Play video playlist and individual video clip from playlist in Loop, AVQueuePlayer iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayeritem, avqueueplayer

I am trying to play video playlist in loop and also play individual video clip from playlist in loop in AVQueuePlayer using AVPlayerItem, but i am unable to find the solution for same below is the code that i have tried so far

General

```
var player : AVQueuePlayer?
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
var playerItem: [AVPlayerItem] = []

func playAtIndex(index:Int){
        for i in index ..< playerItem.count {
            let obj = playerItem[i]
            if (self.player?.canInsert(obj, after: nil))! {
                obj.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
                self.player?.insert(obj, after: nil)
                }
        }
    }
```

Initialise video player

```
self.player = AVQueuePlayer.init(items: self.playerItem)
self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
self.playerLayer?.frame = self.view!.bounds
self.playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
self.view!.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
self.player?.play()
```

code done so far for looping playlist, this works but some of the video from the loop does not play sometimes.

```
self.playAtIndex(index: 0)
```

code done for looping individual video clip in playlist, but does not work

```
let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = note.object as! AVPlayerItem // here we get current item 
playerItem.seek(to: CMTime.zero, completionHandler: nil)
self.player?.play()
```

Any help will be great.!!

Answer (score 0):

To loop the `playerItems` in `AVQueuePlayer`, you need to add a an `observer` to the `notification` - `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`

> A notification that's posted when the item has played to its end time.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerEndedPlaying), name: Notification.Name("AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"), object: nil)
```

The method `playerEndedPlaying(_:)` will be called whenever the `notification` is fired.

```
@objc func playerEndedPlaying(_ notification: Notification) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
        if let playerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
            self?.player?.remove(playerItem)
            playerItem.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
            self?.player?.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
            if playerItem == self?.playerItems?.last {
                self?.pauseVideo()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above method will be called every time a `playerItem` in the `AVQueuePlayer` ends playing.

1. `AVQueuePlayer's` `insert(_:after:)` is called where each `playerItem` is appended to the `queue`.

> afterItem
>
> The player item that the newly inserted player item should
>   follow in the queue. Pass nil to append the item to the queue.

2. Loop is identified using `playerItem == self?.playerItems?.last`. You can add your custom handling here. I've `paused` the `player` once all the `videos` end playing.

Comment: thanks for the brief, but this does not answer to my question.

Comment: it does not play playlist in loop

Comment: Try removing `self?.pauseVideo()` line in the above code.

Comment: it plays only last video in loop

Comment: AVPlayerLooper.loopingPlayerItems perhaps? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper/1643631-loopingplayeritems